# Postsharp dont write logs on server

Tags: c#, .net, iis, logging, postsharp

I use

```
LogAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
```

**OnMethodBoundaryAspect** is postsharp class.

**LogAttribute** I use for logging methods.

On my local machine logs are written. But on IIS server they arent written. On this server the project with the same attributes for logs exists and this project is deployed by tfs 15. I deploy my project manually.

Why do this situation appear?

Comment: Did you give write permissions to your app pool user?

Comment: @Hackerman Yes. my app lays in the same app pool where the project with logs correct works

Comment: Then, are you sure that the folder or files where the logs should be written are not locked for just reading?

Comment: @Hackerman Yes Im sure

Comment: Does TFS 15 deploy PostSharp.dll as well?